# Dialog should not appear twice (or more) after retrigger bootstrap notify funtion

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, notify

I use the [bootstrap notify](http://bootstrap-notify.remabledesigns.com/) for displaying a save function. The problem is, that the user can save multiple.

Example: Every second the button is clicked by the user (Checkbox1, Checkbox2, ...). Every checkbox calles the notify function.

Aim: The dialog should appear for 3 seconds. If the button was click again in the 3 seconds, no further dialog should be appear.
The 3 seconds but should start from scratch (retrigger)

```js
$(function(){
  $(".btn").on("click",function(){
    $.notify({
      title: 'This dialog should appear only once',
      icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-star',
      message: ""
    },{
      type: 'info',
      animate: {
      enter: 'animated fadeInUp',
        exit: 'animated fadeOutRight'
      },
      placement: {
        from: "bottom",
        align: "left"
      },
      offset: 20,
      spacing: 10,
      z_index: 1031,
      timer: 3000,
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mouse0270-bootstrap-notify/3.1.5/bootstrap-notify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.3/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class="btn btn-primary">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *onClosed* event that let you know when the notification has ended, while is opened you can prevent it to be opened again with a flag, that you can change when the onClosed event is fired...

```js
$(function(){
  var busy = false;
  $(".btn").on("click",function(){
    
    
    if(!busy) {
      busy=true;
    $.notify({
      title: 'This dialog should appear only once',
      icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-star',
      message: ""
    },{
      type: 'info',
      animate: {
      enter: 'animated fadeInUp',
        exit: 'animated fadeOutRight'
      },
      placement: {
        from: "bottom",
        align: "left"
      },
      offset: 20,
      spacing: 10,
      z_index: 1031,
      timer: 3000,
      onClosed: function() {
        busy=false;  
      }
    });
    } 
    
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mouse0270-bootstrap-notify/3.1.5/bootstrap-notify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.3/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class="btn btn-primary">click me</button>
```

Comment: Great. Works perfect!